# Chinese hand-writing recognition program for IPhone

Tags: iphone, ocr, cjk

I would like to start on Chinese hand-writing recognition program for IPhone...but I couldn't find any library or API that can help me to do so. It's hard for me to write the algorithm myself because of my time span. 
Some of suggestion recommended that I should make use of a back-end server to do the recognition work. But I don't know how to set up that kind of server.
So any suggestion or basic steps that can help me to achieve this personal project?

Comment: If time is an issue, than you shouldn't be tackling such a large assignment.  This seems like an over-ambitious undergrad project.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you Chinese? I'm not, but my limited understanding suggests that written Chinese is *extremely* complicated. Such a feature may not exist anywhere in the world yet. Computer vision applications have enough trouble with Western script. If you don't know, I'd say this is probably a topic you'd need to discuss with someone on the level of University professors specialising in computer vision.

Comment: If you can't find open source code, this task may be the size of a graduate level research project.  If that's the amount of time you have, then you might start by reading dozens of research papers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out [Zinnia](http://zinnia.sourceforge.net/).  Tegaki relies on other APIs (Zinnia is one of them) to do the actual character recognition.
I haven't looked at the code, but I gather it's written in C or C++, so should suit your needs better than Tegaki.

Comment: Great! Perhaps I would solve the problem... I am porting it to ObjC in no time. Thx